# getElementById doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm new to this website and I'm just learning how to code. My program doesn't write anything or create an input, can someone help me and spot the mistake?

```
<html>
<head><title>array exchange</title></head>
<body>
    <form id="ne" >
    number of array elements: <input type="number" name="el_array" ><br>
        <input type="submit" value="execute" onsubmit="create()">
    </form>
</body>
<script>
    function create(){
    var numel = document.getElementById("ne");

    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "number");

    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I recommend you use `querySelector` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector like such: `document.querySelector('#ne');`

Answer (score 2):

You need to append child  then it will be reflected in DOM

```
numel.appendChild(x)
```

Also use `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"` and `onclick` event handler

```
<input type="button" value="execute" onclick="create()">
```

```js
function create() {
  var numel = document.getElementById("ne");

  var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
  x.setAttribute("type", "number");
  numel.appendChild(x);
}
```

```html
<form id="ne">
  number of array elements: <input type="number" name="el_array"><br>
  <input type="button" value="execute" onclick="create()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read about the usage of the form tag as well for better understanding:

1. https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_form.asp
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Answer (score 1):

İ recommend starting read from MDN.My opinion MDN The best documentation for Javascript:

https://developer.mozilla.org/bm/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Introduction

Answer (score 1):

```js
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "submit";
document.body.appendChild(input);
input.addEventListener("click",function createEl(){
    var numel = document.getElementById("ne");

    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "number");
numel.appendChild(x);
    });
```

```html
<form id="ne" >
    number of array elements: <input type="number" name="el_array" >
  <br>
    </form>
```